# How to get page visit count from access log

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I need to display the list of pages(nodes & terms) from access log. I enabled drupal core statistics module.

The view result should include

1. Page title.
2. Total number of distinct pages($view->total_rows).
3. Total views result($view->result).
4. Individual visit count of pages ().

I created a view and a template. I am getting points #1,#2 & #3 in my view. But #4 is missing.

I checked access log table in DB, but didn't found the column for page view count. How can get the missing point in my view?

Comment: How can i add an exposed search from to this view. It should include content type fields that i added while creating theses pages in views result.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Module Visitors

You may want to consider the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module. As mentioned on its project page, it provides a block containing:

- Total Visitors.
- Unique Visitor.
- Registered Users.
- Last Registered User.
- Published Nodes.
- Your IP.

At this time there is no integration with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module ... yet. All reports created today use the `theme` function. Such views integration is being considered though, i.e. in the format of some out-of-the-box example, similar to the [view delivered with the charts module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426921).

### 2. Module Forena

If you'd want to "roll your own cookies" (i.e. some report that perfectly fits your custom requirements), then you might want to consider the Views integration of the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module. Here is a relevant excerpt about that from its project page:

> Use Views with Forena to create additional more complicated layouts than can typically be created using views. Forena provides a views rowstyle plugin that lets you use a Forena report to format the output of a view.

For an example of such custom report, created with Forena, start from the statistics (summary info) of the Watchdog Statistics, as in this [Watchdog Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/FrxCrosstab.png) sample. Note the red numbers to the right of the table, which are actually hyperlinks that can be used as drill-down reports. I.e. if you click on any of them (like the "2" for "Page not found"), you get a details report about (in this case) the 2 specific records related to the "Page not found"). More details about this specific case can be found in [comment #2 of issue 2337327](https://www.drupal.org/node/2337327#comment-9143781). Obvious, I didn't really do any effort to beef up the look-and-feel of that report, like background, etc.

### 3. Other modules

[Modules related to Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2444205) contains some other modules available, which might be considered as a possible alternative (or maybe 'addition'?), such as the [Views Watchdog](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_watchdog) module.

Disclosure: I'm maintainer of the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module, and co-maintainer of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) and [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Can we integrate visitors module with views?. Is there any option to add an exposed filter to that view?.

Comment: I finished enhancing my answer ... hope it answers your comment from about an hour ago (which got deleted already again I just noticed). Quite some options to consider, no?

Comment: Hi @drup, after I just answered your newest question, I looked at your profile a bit. Hope you don't mind I say so, but I noticed that (a) you never "voted" on anything (proof = you don't have badge "supporter") and (b) you have 48 questions but never marked any of them as "accepted". Therefor this friendly suggestion: consider checking out the "tour" (link within help, upper right), and also what's written in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ... No obligation, just trying to get you going, ok?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable Drupal this core module "**STATISTICS**", after enabling this, go to your view and in view's "**Add fields**" section

1. Click add
2. Select "**Content statistics: Total views**"

This will give you the total number every single page has been viewed.

Comment: Is this applicable for taxonomy term view?.